# Not able call a const variable from service file to component file

Tags: node.js, typescript, angular7

const variable is not re-assigning in method which I am calling from component ngOnInit method.

**ec2.service.ts**

```
private _status = false;

getStatus() {
    const params = {
        InstanceIds: [ 'i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' ]
    };
    ec2.describeInstanceStatus(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err, err.stack);
        } else {
            console.log(data);
            if (data.InstanceStatuses.length === 0) {
                this._status = true;
            }
        }
    });
    console.log(this._status);
    return this._status;
}
```

**component.ts**

```
constructor(public service: EC2Service) { }
ngOnit() {
    console.log(this.service.getStatus());
}
```

Here the condition is true. But it is returning false instead true.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method `describeInstanceStatus` perform async operation. To get the result from async operation you can do using `promise` and `async/await` like below

```
    getStatus() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const params = {
            InstanceIds: [ 'i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' ]
        };
          ec2.describeInstanceStatus(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
               reject(err)
            } else {
                console.log(data);
                if (data.InstanceStatuses.length === 0) {
                   resolve(true)
                }
                reject(false)
            }
        });
    });
   }
```

**component.ts**

```
constructor(public service: EC2Service) { }
async ngOnit() {
    const result = await this.service.getStatus();
     console.log(result)
}
```

Comment: Hi @narayansharma91, even **data.InstancsStatuses.length** is not there, it still returning **true** value

Answer (score 0):

Since  `ec2.describeInstanceStatus` performs an async operation, you need to wait until it finishes. You can use `async/await` syntax.

And you better use `arrow function` in order not lose scope within the callback function.

```
async getStatus() {
    const params = {
        InstanceIds: [ 'i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' ]
    };
    await ec2.describeInstanceStatus(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err, err.stack);
        } else {
            console.log(data);
            if (data.InstanceStatuses.length === 0) {
                this._status = true;
            }
        }
    });
    console.log(this._status);
    return this._status;
}
```

Comment: When I am trying like this, It returns **ZoneAwarePromise {__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: Array(0)}** not true or false